# Syncing height of dijit textareas

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a set of some `dijit/form/Textarea`-dijits in a row on the page, and I'd like for the `height` to be uniform between them, so that if a user types in one `textarea` and causes it to expand, the others expand with it. It would look much neater than having several different-sized `textarea`s in a row.
Anyone done this before? Is there a hook I can get on the resize of a `dijit/form/textarea` to achieve this?

Comment: are you able to use jQuery?

Comment: The project uses Dojo exclusively at the moment, but if you have a jQuery solution I'd be interested to see it :)

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know much about `jQuery`, but I made this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/385Fg/10/) work only for syncing `heigth` of textareas when it changes due to typing-caused. It does not work for the expand functionality.. :(

Comment: now it also responds to manually expanding the textarea using the mouse : http://jsfiddle.net/385Fg/15/